# Css Transform: Scale Only Works in Dev Tools

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve a simple :hover effect where the image hovered scales up when hovered. Strangely, when I click the :hover radio button in the "Force element state" in Chrome dev tools, the effect works as expected, but when I actually hover over the image, no dice. Any insight would be much appreciated!

This is my markup (the image has a semi opaque overlay)

```
<article class="news-loop_item">
  <img 
    src="http://imgsv.imaging.nikon.com/lineup/lens/zoom/normalzoom/af-
    s_dx_18-300mmf_35-56g_ed_vr/img/sample/sample4_l.jpg" class="news-
    loop_img" alt="featured image">
  <div class="news-loop_overlay">
    <h2 class="news-loop_title">Title</h2>
    <p class="news-loop_date">Date</p>
    <div class="news-loop_summary">Summary</div>
  </div>
</article>
```

And my scss

```
.news-loop {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: -1rem;
}

.news-loop_item {
  flex-basis: calc(100% / 2 - 2rem);
  height: 20rem;
  margin: 1rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.news-loop_img {
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
}

.news-loop_img:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.15, 1.15);
  transform: scale(1.15, 1.15);
}

.news-loop_overlay {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out; 
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.news-loop_overlay:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
```

https://codepen.io/evanhickman/pen/ZXOmWb

Comment: Could you creade a [Codepen](https://codepen.io) example with your code? Easier to debug...

Comment: can you provide us with final html/css and not SASS

Comment: @FlorinPop working on that now

Comment: @TemaniAfif I've updated to include plain html/css

Comment: Voting to Close as this question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why is that your hover selector is wrong, check out this:

```
.news-loop_item:hover .news-loop_img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.15, 1.15);
  transform: scale(1.15, 1.15);
}
```

See the parent element needs the hover event.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because your `.news-loop_overlay` class div is 'capturing' the hover effect.

Try adding a `z-index: -1;` to that div and you'll see that the scale works.